# How to find longest way in a maz recursively

Tags: c++

I've written a code to find away in a maze recursively and it works fine. but now I want it to find the longest way from start to end. Does anybody know how should I change my algorithm? (I still want it to be recursive)
thanx!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int POSSIBLE_MOVES =4;
int row_delta[POSSIBLE_MOVES] = {-1,0,1,0};
int col_delta[POSSIBLE_MOVES] = {0,1,0,-1};
int round=0;
int way[3][4]={};

string map[][4]={"s",".",".","#",
        "#",".",".","#",
        "$",".",".","E"};


void print_way()
{
    cout<<"PrintWay:\n";
    for (int i=0;i<3;++i)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<4;++j)
            cout<<way[i][j];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n";
}

int find_tour(int move_no, int current_row, int current_col) {

     cout << move_no << endl;
     print_way();  

    if (map[current_row][current_col]=="E")
        return true;

    for (int move = 0; move < POSSIBLE_MOVES; move++) {
        int new_row = current_row + row_delta[move];
        int new_col = current_col + col_delta[move];

        if (new_row<0 || new_row>=3 || new_col<0 || new_col>=4)
            continue;

        if (way[new_row][new_col]!=0)
            continue;

    if (map[new_row][new_col]=="#")
            continue;

        way[new_row][new_col] = move_no + 1;
        if (find_tour(move_no + 1, new_row, new_col))
            return true;
        way[new_row][new_col] = 0;
    }
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    int m=3;  //row
    int n=4;  //column
    int t=1;  //number of food
    int initRow=0;
    int initCol=0;

    cout<<"\n\ninput\n\n\n";
    cout<<m<<" "<<n<<endl;
    for (int row=0;row<m;++row)        
    {   for (int column=0;column<n;++column)
            cout<<map[row][column];
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<t<<endl;
    cout<<"\nnow the functions are calculating:\n"; 

    way[initRow][initCol]=1;
    find_tour(0,0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is almost the same. But instead of just returning when you have found an exit, you should compare the length of the found path and if it is longer than the previous one then store it somewhere. Than keep searching all other possible ways.
Of course you should mark somehow already visited points, otherwise the longest path to the exit may be infinitely long.